# Interrupt in method

Tags: android

I'm trying to run randomText() method that inside the method I have a loop that each time it waits for 2 sec and then loop run again. Each time it should make a random number 1 or 0. If its 0 shows LEFT and if it makes 1 shows RIGHT. But actually always shows LEFT and doesn't change! I don't know if its the Thread problem or original code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

Button left , right ;
TextView text ;
int value , mistake , pressed ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //value = 0; // 0:left 1:right 2:didnt pressed any
    mistake = 0; // max mistake = 3

    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // value of the key is 0
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); // value of the key is 1
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    randomText();
    //*** set actions

    left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pressed = 1;
            if(value != 0)      { mistake++; }
        }
    });
    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pressed = 1;
            if(value != 1)      { mistake++; }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void randomText(){
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i=0;i<10 && mistake <=2 ;i++){
        value = r.nextInt(2);
        pressed = 0; // 
        if (value == 1)
            text.setText("RIGHT");
        else
            text.setText("LEFT");
        try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // We've been interrupted

            }

         if (pressed == 0)  mistake++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Run it 100 times and see if this is really random - that's the beauty of the random numbers, they can repeat 99 times with value "0" and just one time with "1" or none. As I see from the code, you want this text in the `Textview` to be changed on interval of two seconds (randomly) - right?

Answer (score 0):

For one, you are calling randomText() in your main thread. This means that, because you set pressed to 0 inside the loop, it will remain 0 unless you change it in a different thread. Button clicks also happen on the main thread, so they can't change pressed to something else while randomText() is being executed.

This means that you get exactly three iterations in your randomText() method before it stops calling text.setText().

Furthermore, you should be calling the Random(long seed) constructor for your Random r. It's generally recommended to use the current time for a seed, so your Random object should initialize like so:

```
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```